# Binding a Linq Query to a ListView in a WPF window

Tags: wpf, linq, listview

I am looking an example of the following:

I have a WPF window with a listview (or in fact any object would be fine if it works better).
I have a rather complex linq query (I know the query is correct as I have tested in Linqpad).
In the query there a couple of dummy fields which I will have to fill in with a supplementary query.

I would like to:

1. Bind some elements of the query to the list view
2. Update the dummy fields in the list view using the
   supplementary query
3. Be able to select one line in the list to go to a detail window with the full line from the query and the extra data I updated in the dummy fields

Thanx for any help.

Mark

Here is the code from the window/object

```
    public statesPerVersion(TPClient.Application _Application, TPlanPro.TPlanSession _Session, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<String, String> _dConnect, TPlanPro.Node _mvNode)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _app = _Application;
        _session = _Session;
        _func = new CSNetFunctions.Functions(_session, _app, _dConnect);
        TTNavDB01DataContext _navDB = new TTNavDB01DataContext(_dConnect[Functions._nav]);
        var getStates = from s in _navDB.TP_MT_Scripts
                        join ss in _navDB.MT_ScriptStates on new { s.tpID, s.ComponentTC_ID } equals new { ss.tpID, ss.ComponentTC_ID }
                        join st in _navDB.MT_States on ss.StateID equals st.ID
                        join pr in _navDB.TE_ProductReleases on ss.ProductReleaseID equals pr.ProductReleaseId
                        //where s.TpMVersionID == "19E04398FB82435CB21A80EFEBAD62AF"
                        where s.tpMVersionID == _mvNode.Id.ToString()
                        orderby s.TestCaseID ascending, ss.ID descending
                        select new
                        {
                            s.ComponentTC_ID,
                            s.tpID,
                            s.TestCaseID,
                            ss.ID,
                            st.State,
                            ss.StateDate,
                            ss.StateBy,
                            pr.TeamTrackName,
                            ss.Comments,
                            Locked = true,
                            Bypassed = true,
                            s.ExternalScript,
                            s.EquContract,
                            s.FinContract,
                            s.ScriptType
                        } ;

        var groupStates = from gs in getStates group gs by new { gs.TestCaseID } into gsGroup select new { ls = gsGroup.First() };
        scriptList.DataContext = groupStates;

    }
```

And here is the code from the xaml

```
Window x:Class="CSNetWindows.statesPerVersion"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="View latest Script states for Version " Height="267" Width="825">
    <Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="scriptList" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="TestCase" Width="50" 
      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ls.TestCaseID}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="State" Width="50" 
      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ls.State}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Date" Width="50" 
      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ls.StateDate}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Tester" Width="50" 
      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ls.StateBy}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Release" Width="50" 
      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ls.TeamTrackName}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Locked" Width="50" 
      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ls.Locked}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="ByPassed" Width="50" 
      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ls.ByPassed}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="External Script" Width="50" 
      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ls.ExternalScript}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Equ Contract" Width="50" 
      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ls.EquContract}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Fin Contract" Width="50" 
      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ls.FinContract}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Type" Width="50" 
      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ls.FinContract}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Comments" Width="50" 
      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ls.ScriptType}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why have your LINQ query return a List where SomeStruct represents the structure you've shown above but allows you to make your edits, etc.? And then you would bind it to the GridView after making the edits. To pass the selected item on to the next "page" you may need to store the selected item in a global variable somewhere and pick it up from the second page.